# How to display User Mapping for offline databases?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, users, logins, offline

When I use the GUI (SSMS) to review the User Mapping, where the Login has mapping to a database that is offline (*or otherwise not available*) I get the message below and it only displays Mapping for databases that are online.

> One or more databases are inaccessible and will not be displayed in list

All the details should actually be in the Master DB, there should be something I can run that will show me what the full User Mapping is.

How can I display User Mapping for offline databases?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.databases` joined with `sys.server_principals`

```
SELECT sd.NAME AS databaseName
    ,sp.NAME AS database_owner
FROM sys.databases sd
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON sd.owner_sid = sp.SID
WHERE sd.state_desc = 'OFFLINE' --> since you want for offline databases !
```

[image]

You can even use at your own risk --> [`sp_msloginmappings`](http://www.g-productions.nl/index.php?name=sp_MSloginmappings) ( **<-- Undocumented and unsupported** :-) )

Comment: That helps, I would also like to be able to see if they are a user on a database not just the owner.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a false assumption here

> All the details should actually be in the Master DB, there should be something I can run that will show me what the full User Mapping is.

Consider that if you restore a backup from one instance to another, the database brings over all the existing users (database detail) without there having been a login (instance detail) created.

Even if you could query the master database for user information about offline databases it would only include information where a login exists.  Any users that have database user accounts without a login, would not be identified.

No one can read an offline database, your only option is to set the database to read-only, find what you want and set it back to offline (assuming it is offline for a reason)